# Syntax Error while preforming One-Way ANOVA test with statsmodel

Tags: python, statsmodels, anova

I have been trying to perform a one-way ANOVA test with statsmodel from a pandas data frame as follows

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

mod = ols('DOSE DELIVERED ~ TYPE', data = df_chosen).fit()
aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod, typ =2)
print(aov_table)
```

However I keep getting this syntax error. I have checked that the spell of the categories make sense but nothing works.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-25-364084670c42>", line 1, in <module>
    mod = ols('DOSE DELIVERED ~ TYPE', data = df_chosen).fit()

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 159, in from_formula
    missing=missing)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\formulatools.py", line 65, in handle_formula_data
    NA_action=na_action)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py", line 310, in dmatrices
    NA_action, return_type)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py", line 165, in _do_highlevel_design
    NA_action)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py", line 70, in _try_incr_builders
    NA_action)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py", line 689, in design_matrix_builders
    factor_states = _factors_memorize(all_factors, data_iter_maker, eval_env)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py", line 354, in _factors_memorize
    which_pass = factor.memorize_passes_needed(state, eval_env)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py", line 474, in memorize_passes_needed
    subset_names = [name for name in ast_names(self.code)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py", line 474, in <listcomp>
    subset_names = [name for name in ast_names(self.code)

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py", line 105, in ast_names
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code)):

  File "C:\Users\Home\Anaconda_3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    DOSE DELIVERED
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax error when creating statsmodels Model from formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940464/syntax-error-when-creating-statsmodels-model-from-formula)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have spaces in the formula variable names.

You have to rename `DOSE DELIVERED` into `DOSE_DELIVERED` or they'd be seen as two variables `DOSE` and `DELIVERED`.